# Rosbag file location

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know where are rosbags saved to access them through my file explorer (if that is possible).

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360073/rosbag-file-location/) by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I found the answer here: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data

So it's necessary to create a directory to store the bag files: `mkdir ~/bagfiles`

---

Originally posted by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) with karma: 38 on 2020-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-08-21**:\

> it's necessary to create a directory to store the bag files

Not really, when you record a bag file it will be stored at the same location as you were when doing `rosbag record`, the tutorial tells you to create the folder bagfile and then go to this new directory to have your bagfile at this location. If you are not in the folder `bagfiles` when issuing `rosbag record`, it won't be stored there.

You can use the argument `-o` to add a prefix to the bagfile name, if you specify an absolute path from then you can choose the location :

```
rosbag record -a -o $HOME/bagfiles/
```

This command will save your bagfile in your `~/bagfiles` folder regardless of which directory you are currently in.

**Comment by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) on 2020-08-23**:
Perfect! Now I understand.